# Flutter Change Colors by Theme

Tags: flutter

I add this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_theme) to my project.

This works but I want to change the color of a container, for example, depending on which theme is selected. How can I do that?

Comment: You can check the current theme using `Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark` but a better approach would be to define a `themeData` object & use the appropriate `themeData` object depending upon the selected theme. For ex. `kDarkTheme = ThemeData(...), kLightTheme = ThemeData(...)` etc & pass this `themeData` object to `MaterialApp`.

Comment: and how do i address the individual containers and texts? i want to have different containers in different colors

Comment: Can you post a simple short example explaining the feature you want?

Comment: if is Dark theme active i need this for example

container(Color: Colors.red) and if is not active
container(Color: Colors.green)

Comment: `Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? Colors.red : Colors.green`. You can also create a helper method for this.

Comment: You know like

`Color getThemeColor({@required Color darkThemeColor,@required Color lightThemeColor}) => Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? darkThemeColor : lightThemeColor;`
And you can call this method in your `Container`'s color property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper method `getThemeColor` as follows:

```
Color getThemeColor({@required Color darkThemeColor,@required Color lightThemeColor}) { 
    return Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? darkThemeColor : lightThemeColor;
}
```

And then use this wherever you want to set your color:

```
Container(
  color: getThemeColor(darkThemeColor: Colors.red, lightThemeColor: Colors.green),
),
```